# Select top duplicate record

Tags: sql

I currently have multiple records but I only need one record. I have tried Cross apply but it seems like I am missing something that I myself can't seem to ping. Instead, I get a whole different value that it is not even in the record in the table provided.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
id         subject          enrollmentdate    roomNum  
00045       science         3-3-2016             98
00045       science         3-3-2016             52
00089       math            7-25-2017            13
00089       math            7-25-2017            56
00123       social studies  3-1-2016             02
00136       gym             5-2-2017             01
00159       math            9-2-2017             96
```

query:

```
select  d.id, c.subject, c.Enrollmentdate, ds.roomNum
from  #classrooms as c 
 cross apply 
     (select top 1 roomNum, subject,Enrollmentdate
      from  #classrooms 
      where subject = c.subject
      and enrollmentdate = c.enrollmentdate
      order by id desc) as ds
```

Result:

```
 id         subject          enrollmentdate    roomNum  
    00045       science         3-3-2016             66
    00045       science         3-3-2016             66
```

Comment: Which record do you want to select and by what rule can we find it?

Comment: Grouping similar rows seems to be what you need. Can you give an example of which rows you want to group? What are the columns you would include in your "is similar" comparison?

Answer (score 3):

If you need only one (and don't care much *which one*), then something like this might help:

```
select id, 
       subject, 
       enrollmentdate, 
       max(roomnum) max_roomnum
from #classrooms
group by id, 
         subject, 
         enrollmentdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular one, you can use `top with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties c.*
from #classrooms c
order by row_number() over (partition by id, subject, enrollmentdate order by roomNum desc);
```

Or for a truly random one:

```
select top (1) with ties c.*
from #classrooms c
order by row_number() over (partition by id, subject, enrollmentdate order by newid() desc);
```